# Virtualbox won't start after recent windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

After upgrading to `Build 14295.rs1_release.160318-1628`, virtualbox won't start.
Got this in the Event Viewer:

(1):

```
Faulting application name: VirtualBox.exe, version: 5.0.16.5871, time stamp: 0x56d9b7eb
Faulting module name: VirtualBox.exe, version: 5.0.16.5871, time stamp: 0x56d9b7eb
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000001a432
Faulting process id: 0x22e4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d18cf9d6141ade
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
Report Id: 0ba2e59e-e6aa-400d-905f-19e8aaa74d63
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

(2):

```
Fault bucket 120426854152, type 4
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: VirtualBox.exe
P2: 5.0.16.5871
P3: 56d9b7eb
P4: VirtualBox.exe
P5: 5.0.16.5871
P6: 56d9b7eb
P7: c0000005
P8: 000000000001a432
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER9550.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_VirtualBox.exe_63389d7adf28e3cbb0622cb6b9dfb5a8879699b5_d20cf6ba_235e9aee

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 0ba2e59e-e6aa-400d-905f-19e8aaa74d63
Report Status: 0
Hashed bucket: 60353ba07915e7e823694bedb76dcf8c
```

At first I was running 5.0.14 version but when this happened I upgraded to 5.0.16 but problem still remains.
Anyone got this issue?

-Edit-
Just found out it's possible to roll back to previous build (in my case it's version 1511, os build 10586.164) `Settings -> Recovery -> Go back to an earlier build` and virtualbox working again.

Comment: It works well for me. Not that that helps you, know.

Comment: VirtualBox is known to have problems with Windows 10, it has had problems in the past, running a Insider Preview version of Windows 10 and having software fail to work is a risk of doing just that running a pre-released build.

Answer (score 5):

There were changes in Build 14295.rs1_release.160318-1628 that broke Virtualbox, but the Virtualbox team are aware of the issues and the latest test builds have corrected this. This file works for me:
https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VirtualBox-5.0.17-106344-Win.exe

If you want further info see here:
https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15245
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=76813
feedback-hub:?contextid=156&feedbackid=81357525-4f41-4507-9f4d-35f1ca987e52&form=1&src=2 (paste link into explorer within windows)

Or for anyone else who finds Virtualbox issues on Win 10, see here and wants to try the latest test build, it should be available here:
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when I updated windows 10. It is not even open any window when I try to open the VM application. So I just downloaded `VM latest version` from

> https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

and installed. On run it showed all the previous VM images that I installed. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the original Virtual machine folder under the directory OS(C:)/users/user_name/VirtualBox_VMs is intact.

Uninstall and reinstall the current version of VirtualBox.

The new version should point to this folder and your old Vms will be intact.